# How to Skip over a Non-Existing Object in a JSON Array

Tags: json

I am parsing the following JSON Message hereafter with the jQuery Function below. As seen by observing the JSON Message, the second Object in the friends.data Array does not have any “statuses” Item, but only “name” and “id”, contrary to the first and last objects in the Main Array. Nevertheless, I am having issues parsing the entire Message since the $.each(friend.statuses, function(j, status) Function stops at the second Item (which does not have any “statuses” entry) without proceeding to the next one (last one in this example), which does contain a “statuses” Item. I have tried adding some logic before and after the $.each(friend.statuses, function(j, status) Function in order to verify if there is an existing Item (“statuses”), but without success. How could I “Skip” over this second Item in the Main Array, so that the second $.each Function continues to parse the Main Array until the end of the JSON Message.

```
Function:

$.each(response.friends.data, function(i, friend){
    $.each(friend.statuses, function(j, status){
        alert(status.message);
    });
});



JSON Message:

{   
    "id": "idValue",
    "friends": {
      "data": [
       {
         "name": "NameValue",
         "id": "idValue",
         "statuses": {
           "data": [
             {
               "message": "Msg1",
               "updated_time": "Date",
             },
             {
               "message": "Msg2",
               "updated_time": "Date",
             },
           ],
          }
       },

       {
         "name": "NameValue",
         "id": "idValue",
       }

       {
         "name": "NameValue",
         "id": "idValue",
         "statuses": {
           "data": [
             {
               "message": "Msg1",
               "updated_time": "Date",
             },
             {
           "message": "Msg2",
               "updated_time": "Date",
             },
           ],
         }
       }
     ],   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the current `friend` object has statuses, if it doesn't then continue to the next friend. You can do this by just doing: `if(!friend.statuses) return;`

```
$.each(response.friends.data, function(i, friend){
    if(!friend.statuses) return;
    $.each(friend.statuses, function(j, status){
        alert(status.message);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you both for your answers. I have used the answer from ggreiner since it appeared simpler and straightforward, and it worked wonderfully. Thank you again both for your time.

Regards,

JF

Answer (score 1):

You might [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array :

```
$.each(
    response.friends.data.filter(function(){return typeof this.status!='undefined'}),
     function(i, friend){
    $.each(friend.statuses, function(j, status){
        alert(status.message);
    });
});
```

(note the solution proposed in the doc if you want to be compatible with IE8-)